# Getting my userName from MS teams with javascript/reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, microsoft-teams

Im trying to get my Teams userPrincipalname out of the context and using it in a fetch URL. Unfortunately its not actually saving my userPrincipalName within {userPrincipalName} but instead it contains: [object Object]

As i can see in the URL its trying to fetch: http://localhost/openims/json.php?function=getDocuments&input=%22[object%20Object]%22

The URL returns the following: `{"name":"[object Object]","age":26,"city":"London"}`

What am i doing wrong here?

The code:

```
import React from 'react';
import './App.css';
import * as microsoftTeams from "@microsoft/teams-js";

class Tab extends React.Component {
  constructor(props){
    super(props)
    this.state = {
      context: {}
    }
  }

  componentDidMount(){
    microsoftTeams.getContext((context, error) => {
      this.setState({
        context: context
      });
    });
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    const { userPrincipalName } = this.state.context;
    fetch('http://localhost/openims/json.php?function=getDocuments&input='+'"'+ {userPrincipalName} +'"')
      .then(res => res.json())
      .then((result) => {
        this.setState({ ...result });
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        this.setState({ error });
      })
      .finally(() => {
        this.setState({ isLoaded: true })
      });
  }
  
  render() {  
    const { error, isLoaded, name, age, city } = this.state;
    if (error) {
      return <div>Error: {error.message}</div>;
    } else if (!isLoaded) {
      return <div>Loading...</div>;
    } else {
      return (     
        <ul>
          <li>
            {name} {age} {city}
          </li>
        </ul>       
      );
    }
  }

}
export default Tab;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problems I can see are that you need to ensure:

- `microsoftTeams.getContext` takes a callback, so promisify it and then you use `then` on it (like any promise)
- once you've got the `context`, create a URL dynamically using the value of `context.userPrincipalName`
- the final fetch request (to `/openims/json.php` endpoint) only happens once all of the above has happened

That should be something like the following (although re-writing your component as functional component would allow you to use React hooks and better handle any cleanup required).

```js
import React from "react";
import "./App.css";
import * as microsoftTeams from "@microsoft/teams-js";

class Tab extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { context: {} };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    new Promise((resolve) => {
      microsoftTeams.getContext(resolve);
    })
      .then((context) => {
        this.setState({ context });
        const queryParameters = new URLSearchParams({
          function: "getDocuments",
          input: `"${context.userPrincipalName}"`,
        });
        console.log(`userPrincipalName is '${context.userPrincipalName}'`);
        return fetch(`http://localhost/openims/json.php?${queryParameters}`);
      })
      .then((res) => res.json())
      .then((result) => this.setState({ ...result }))
      .catch((error) => this.setState({ error }))
      .finally(() => this.setState({ isLoaded: true }));
  }

  render() {
    const { error, isLoaded, name, age, city } = this.state;
    if (error) {
      return <div>Error: {error.message}</div>;
    } else if (!isLoaded) {
      return <div>Loading...</div>;
    } else {
      return (
        <ul>
          <li>
            {name} {age} {city}
          </li>
        </ul>
      );
    }
  }
}

export default Tab;
```

Comment: the problem seems to be {userPrincipalName} is undefined, even with your suggested fetch the URL its fetching becomes: `http://localhost/openims/json.php?function=getDocuments&input=undefined`
Somehow its not getting the userPrincipalName from the this.state.context

Comment: @7BitAscii, there are two `componentDidMount` methods defined in the code in the original post. I've edited my answer to address the main points.

Comment: this works, however, i need the input (in this case userPrincipalName) to be a string in the URL. So i somehow need to add in `"` before and after the userPrincipalName. How do i do this in the current fix? the link eventually needs to look like this: `http://localhost/openims/json.php?function=getDocuments&input="bla.bla%40testsite.onmicrosoft.com"` So all im missing right now is those `"` characters. On a side note: opening my localhost:3000/tab doesnt actually do the fetch anymore, its just doing the fetch within my teams page. How come?

Comment: The `"` in the example you've provided aren't URL encoded. Is that what your server/PHP script is expecting? I've updated the `queryParameters` to include but also URL encode the `"`. Regarding the fetch only happening on the teams page, there isn't enough information about your context/application to know what you mean. From a React perspective, the fetch request should happen each time the `Tab` component mounts, since the `getContext` and `fetch` logic are defined within the `componentDidMount` lifecycle method.

Comment: Thank you so much for you help, your answer did exactly what i was trying to get done!

Answer (score 0):

Could you please try with below working code.

```
import React from 'react';
import * as microsoftTeams from "@microsoft/teams-js";
class Tab extends React.Component {

  constructor(props){

    super(props)

    this.state = {

      context: {}

    }

  }



  //React lifecycle method that gets called once a component has finished mounting

  //Learn more: https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#componentdidmount

  componentDidMount(){

    // Get the user context from Teams and set it in the state

    microsoftTeams.getContext((context, error) => {

      this.setState({

        context: context

      });

    });

    // Next steps: Error handling using the error object

  }



  render() {



      let userName = Object.keys(this.state.context).length > 0 ? this.state.context['upn'] : "";



      return (

      <div>

        <h3>Hello World!</h3>

        <h1>Congratulations {userName}!</h1> <h3>This is the tab you made :-)</h3>

      </div>

      );

  }

}

export default Tab;
```